# Cursor based pagination - What if the "before" or "after" object get deleted?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, twitter, pagination

Below is the example of Facebook cursor based pagination
```

```
{
  "data": [
     ... Endpoint data is here
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "after": "MTAxNTExOTQ1MjAwNzI5NDE=",
      "before": "NDMyNzQyODI3OTQw"
    },
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?limit=25&before=NDMyNzQyODI3OTQw"
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?limit=25&after=MTAxNTExOTQ1MjAwNzI5NDE="
  }
}
```

```
I guess when get a request like this, server will find the "after" object and get its creation time, then search for items "later" than this object, right?

My question: is "after" and "before" normal object id? What if when paginating those object get deleted?

Comment: why don´t you just test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The before and after parameters can be decoded with base64

```
$ echo "MTAxNTExOTQ1MjAwNzI5NDE=" | base64 --decode
10151194520072941
```

This links to https://www.facebook.com/matthewjohnston4/media_set?set=a.10151194520072941.476776.825212940&type=1

```
$ echo "NDMyNzQyODI3OTQw" | base64 --decode
432742827940
```

And this links to https://www.facebook.com/matthewjohnston4/media_set?set=a.432742827940.204642.825212940&type=1

If you delete the after object it will still get the next item *after* that object.

The easiest way is to just test it yourself.

Comment: If the "after" item get deleted, how do I know the position and get the next item after that?

Comment: @Edmond you don't need to. if you delete the after item, future pagination objects are changed. The only way there will be a contradiction is that you request the page with the after object and then delete the object before select the next link. Since it's the cursor (it's pointing to the object it's not the actual object), I'm pretty sure continuity will be maintained.  Again for the second time, *The easiest way is to just test it yourself.*

Comment: I'm not trying to use Facebook Graph API itself. I'm implementing the pagination mechanism so hoping to know some details. I'm assuming that, when get the second request which contains "after=MTAxNTExOTQ1MjAwNzI5NDE", I should find this object in my system, get it's timestamp(for time based sort only), and search for items created later than this object, right? The thing I don't understand is that, what if the "after" object itself is deleted? Then I lose all the information, right? Then how do I paginate the user? Are you indicating that we should store the virtual object in a separate table?